# How to generate new aspx page dynamically?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, auto-generate

I couldn't find an answer for my question anywhere.

I'm building a website shop in webforms `aspx`, i created a page which insert new product to my database.

how can i do, that once i created a product, it will automatically create a new page for that product (with design that i will pre-define for all new products)?

(same idea for example in facebook, once a new user register, the system automatically create a new page for that user wall/timeline)

Comment: Think about the URL  rewriting . Every product will come with unique URL.

Comment: Mostly websites don't create dynamic pages rather render content dynamically. As @Sami pointed out, you should look url rewriting or if you are asp.net 4.0 or up check this [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/url-routing-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series)

Answer (score 0):

" it will automatically create a new page for that product"?

If you already have an "Add Product" page working then all you have to do to display any/all products is to have a generic page with a ListView? Why the need to dynamically create 100's of unnecessary pages?

Same concept for a new user - one generic page can be used to display data for any user.